# Ignore Excel formatting when querying

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

Using C# i am importing a set of data from Excel. The problem is that Excel tries to "help" by giving fields formats. This causes my application to show incorrect data.

For example, the column in Excel is a "Percentage" column. In this scenario the percentage column is used to store the completion rate, but besides percentages it can also have text values like "Completed", "Not started", "Discontinued". But when i load in the Excel sheet the percentages become numbers (100% becomes 1, 50% becomes 0,5 and so on) and the text values become blanks.

Is there a way to force to get the flat text from the excel file ignoring any formatting?

The code used is :

```
            string ExcelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

            OleDbConnection_Excel = new OleDbConnection(ExcelConnectionString);
            OleDbConnection_Excel.Open();               
            Datatable_CheckSheet = OleDbConnection_Excel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            if (Datatable_CheckSheet == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data Found");
            }
            else
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter OleDbDataAdapter_FillCommand;
                DataTable DataTable_ExcelImport;

                OleDbDataAdapter_FillCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + Datatable_CheckSheet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]", OleDbConnection_Excel);
                DataTable_ExcelImport = new DataTable();
                OleDbDataAdapter_FillCommand.Fill(DataTable_ExcelImport);
                                    BindingSource BindingDataSource_ExcelView = new BindingSource
                {
                    DataSource = DataTable_ExcelImport
                };
                datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                datagridview1.DataSource = BindingDataSource_ExcelView;
            }
```

Comment: Just FYI, that is not Excel helping (it's not even involved in the process), it's the OLEDB provider trying to determine what the data type is. Also, no there is no reliable way to avoid this that I know of.

Comment: @Rory sometimes i really hate automated help things like this... even in just the base excel :|

Comment: The spreadshseet has the cells set to GENERALformating where excel is guessing the format.  The solution is to change the GENERAL cell format to a specific format so the excel driver (either JET or ACE) is not guessing.  Then you need to add the the OleDbConnection parameters with the type of each field.

Answer (score 0):

Since Excel does not have a true schema like other databases, the driver looks at the first rows of data to "guess" at the data type of the column. If the first rows of your data are all numeric, it will treat the entire column as numeric.

Add the extended property `IMEX=1` to your connection string to treat all data as text (strings):

```
";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1"""
```

Note that this treats ALL columns as string columns, even if all data is numeric, so it might require additional parsing that you didn;t need before, but it prevents the driver from

Comment: It made no difference whatsoever :<

Comment: Did it at least show the string values? You may still need to parse and reformat the numeric values.

Comment: no just like before it showed the converted values (100% becoming 1, none percentage strings just being empty)

Comment: @A.bakker Try putting quotes around the extended properties - I updated the example in my answer.

Comment: Already did that before you edited seeing it threw an error. Maybe it has soemthing to do with the Excel file itself :/